# Should I declare UK visa refusal from more than 10 years ago while applying for uk visa on visa4uk?

Tags: visas, uk

I was refused a UK tourist visa in Feb. 2009 because I didn't present enough documentation or evidence to support my application. When I went on [visa4uk's](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/User/Home) application it asked: "Have you been refused a visa for any country including the UK in the last 10 years?" Should I say no because it's technically a "no"? Or should I mention the refusal even though it's been more than 10 years? The other application on [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk) instead asks if a person has been refused a visa, period.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you need to declare the refusal because the ECO will run a background check on you and definitely will see your past refusal... and also state the reason for the refusal... If you hide this information you may be banned for 10years, so it’s best you answer honestly. Wish u all the best